# Angular: Extend a service with multiple children

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, extends

Extending a service from multiple children creates new instances of the services. I want to be able to extend a service and if data changes from one child it should also be available from another child.

I have tried creating a service. I have created two modules which both are extending the service.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {
    //Api stuff going on here
    constructor(){

    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService extends BaseService {
    //Login stuff going on there
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}

export class LoginPage extends AuthService {
    //Handles login
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService extends AuthService {
    //User stuff going on here
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}

export class ProfilePage extends UserService {
    //Handles user stuff
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}

//So LoginPage and UserService are both extending AuthService. For example
//setting a token from LoginPage ->AuthService should make the token available //in the UserService. But how it is now is that it creates multiple instances //of AuthService. Is this even possible to accomplish?
```

I want to know if this is possible. I know the basic way of injecting services, but this is way cooler and way more practical.

Comment: why you need base service? you can create service with common method and inject it?

Comment: Yes, but that's kind of what I was thinking if I could avoid that by extending those services instead.

Consider it like branches
ApiService -> AuthService -> LoginPage ////break here
ApiService -> AuthService -> UserService -> ProfilePage